# How can I get and print correctly a session in php?

Tags: php, session, slim

I have this php that start a session if `$msj` is "si" :

```
<?php

require "dao/daoLoginUsu.php";  

class LoginUsuario{

    public function setDatos($aInput) {

        $obj = json_decode($aInput, true);

       $Dao = new daoLoginUsuario();
       $Dao->setDataDato($obj);

       $msj = $Dao->setDataDato($obj);

       if($msj == 'si'){
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['msj'] = 'si';
       }

      return $msj;   

       } 

       }
    ?>
```

And in this php I want print the session :

```
<?php

session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

and then..

```
if($_SESSION['msj'] == 'si'){.....
```

but when is "si" `print_r($_SESSION);` print:

```
    Array
(
    [slim.flash] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Why I can't print the session?

Comment: You have to be more specific with your question. What's in "/daoLoginUsu.php"; " what are you including there?

Answer (score 0):

The $_SESSION is just a global array in PHP, so like any array, it can be outputted using `var_dump()`.  Some formatting makes the output more readable.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to call session_start() at the top of all the pages that use the session in your program.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
<?php

 session_start();

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_SESSION);
 echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['msj'];
?>
```